# Django CreateView field labels

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I'm working on a project that has a Chapter, with each Chapter having a title, content, and order. I'd like to keep the field 'order' named as is, but have the field displayed in a CreateView as something else, like 'Chapter number'. The best information I've found recommends updating the "labels" attribute in the Meta class, but this isn't working for me.

This is what I'm using now, which doesn't work:

```
class ChapterCreate(CreateView):
    model = models.Chapter
    fields = [
        'title',
        'content',
        'order',
    ]

    class Meta:
        labels = {
            'order': _('Chapter number'),
        }
```

I've also tried using the 'label's attribute outside of Meta, but that didn't work either. Should I be using a ModelForm instead, or is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest solution in this case would be to set the [verbose_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#verbose-name) for your model field

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField(verbose_name= _('Chapter number'))
```

Note I have use IntegerField in this example, please use whatever type is required.

Comment: Awesome, that did it and it's nice and easy. Thank you very much!

Comment: glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is an old subject, I think a way to do this now with Django 3.1 would be:

in views.py

```
class ChapterCreate(CreateView):
    model = models.Chapter
    form_class = ChapterForm
```

and in forms.py, define ChapterForm

```
class ChapterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:    
        model = models.Chapter
        fields = ('title', 'content','order') 
        labels = {
            'order': _('Chapter number'),
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want different values for the `verbose_name` of the model field and the user-facing label of the form field, the quickest way might be to override the `get_form(…)` method of `CreateView`:

```
class ChapterCreate(CreateView):
    (...)

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['order'].label = _('Chapter number')
        return form
```